# Optimizing dictionary translation in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-file

I am using logstash to parse data from a csv file and push it to elasticsearch. I have a dictionary with 600k lines, which uses one of the fields as a key to map it to a string of values. I am currently using the translate plugin like this to achieve what I need

```
filter {
        translate {
            dictionary_path => "somepath"
            field => "myfield"
            override => false
            destination => "destinationField"
        }
    }
```

I get a comma separated String in my destinationField which I read using

```
filter{
    csv {
        source => "destinationField"
        columns => ["col1","col2","col3"]            
        separator => ","
      }

}
```

The result of adding these 2 blocks has increased my processing time by 3x. If it used to take 1 min to process and push all my data, it is now taking 3min to complete the task.

Is this the expected behavior (It is a large dictionary)? Or is there any way to further optimize this code?

Comment: Well, if you include additional processing steps in your pipeline, you can only expect that the processing time increases, right?

Comment: True! but then the processing time going up by 3x seems to be a lot. Was curious to know if there was a more optimized way to go about this

Comment: With a single line you can make it go up to 10x more. In the end it all depends on how those filters are implemented. I'm not too worried about the `csv` one but you may want to investigate the `translate` one.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm looking into the plugin implementation to see if I can understand it better.  Any suggestions on how else I could implement this?

Comment: translate{} should be a hash lookup, which should have minimal overhead.  You can pinpoint how much of the slowdown is attributable to each filter by commenting out the csv{} and running your test again.

Comment: if you're using Logstash 5.2, you can now also use the [monitoring UI](https://www.elastic.co/blog/monitoring-logstash-filters) to better understand where the time is spent.

Comment: @AlainCollins I had tried that out. it is not the csv filter that is causing the overhead but the translate. and as you said it is simply a hash lookup. I'm not able to understand why it is causing an overhead in the first place.

Comment: have you given logstash enough memory to cover increase of the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

The `csv` filter can be expensive.  I wrote a plugin [logstash-filter-augment](https://github.com/alcanzar/logstash-filter-augment/) that works nearly identically to `translate` but handles a native CSV document better.  You can use a real CSV rather than `csv` filter to parse a field.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out. Using this seems a lot cleaner than using two filter blocks